# Converting a block to XML element with Value AND XML attributes using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

First to say: we are no experience XSLT programmers.

Our current system does not have the possibility to export xml elements with attributes. The system only creates blocks and members. There for we though out an alternative with a block for an element and then using XSLT to convert the "dummy" element to a real element with the value of the first child and attributes based on the other childs.

The original xml is:

```html
<block id="ELEM_InvoiceTypeCode">
 <members>
  <member id="InvoiceTypeCode">380</member>
  <member id="listID">UNCL1001</member>
  <member id="listAgencyID">6</member>
 </members>
</block>
```

Our goal is to get the xml below:

```html
<cbc:InvoiceTypeCode listAgencyID="6" listID="UNCL1001">380</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
```

Can someone please help with the needed XSLT? We can find a lot about creating an element with attributes, but nother about also adding the value to the element. See below the code we wanted to use, but was not allowed.

```html
<xsl:element name="cbc:{substring(@id,6,999)}">
 <xsl:value-of select="members/*[1]"/>
 <xsl:for-each select="members/member">
  <xsl:attribute name="{@id}">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>
```

Does someone know how this can be done using XSLT?

Comment: It should work if you put the xsl:for-each before the xsl:value-of. (You need to create the attributes before any content.)

Comment: Also, if the block id always starts with `ELEM_`, changing `substring(@id,6,999)` to `substring-after(@id,'ELEM_')` is easier to understand imo.

Answer (score 0):

The template to perform your task should do the following:

- Save *id* attribute of the first *member* (variable *id1*).
- Save the content of the first *member* (variable *val1*).
- Create a new element with name *cbc:* and the content of *id1* variable.
- For each *member*, except the first, create an attribute with:

  - name taken from its *id* attribute,
  - value taken from its content.
- So far we are done with attributes.
- The last part is to fill the value of this element with the content
  of *val1* variable.

Another issue is how to deal with namespaces.
The `stylesheet` tag must include namespace declaration for `cbc`.
I used here a dummy name, replace it with your own.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:cbc="urn:dummy">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/block/members">
    <xsl:variable name="id1" select="member[1]/@id"/>
    <xsl:variable name="val1" select="member[1]"/>
    <xsl:element name="cbc:{$id1}">
      <xsl:for-each select="subsequence(member,2)">
        <xsl:attribute name="{@id}" select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:value-of select="$val1"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For your input this script generates:

```
<cbc:InvoiceTypeCode xmlns:cbc="urn:dummy" listID="UNCL1001" listAgencyID="6">380</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
```

The difference is that it includes `xmlns:cbc` declaration, but this
is required due to proper XML formatting.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. With your input I managed to create the expected output.

Comment: OK. It would be good if you marked my answer as "selected" (then the application awards reputation points).